# Substitution Method to Solve Recurrences

Tags: induction

One approach to solve recurrences is the so called substitution method.

While practicing I encountered some recurrences, where non integer arguments can occur, e.g. T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n, if n is not a power of 2.

My understanding of the substitution method, is that it only works, if all arguments are integers. Is this correct? Is is it reasonable to apply the substitution method to lower and upper bounds instead, e.g. T(n) ≤ T1(n), where T1(n) = 2*T1(ceil(n/2)) + n, in order to draw conclusions regarding T?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we write $n/2$ we actually mean $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ or $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

In terms of big-O notation, usually they are equivalent (unless you are in some extreme case like $2^{2^x}$ where subtructing or adding $1$ to $x$ could make a significant increase or decrease).

So you can just treat it like a whole number.